# Error executing child request: 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. after adding a validationmessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having this error and scavenged S.O. for answers. I used the [childonly], added the controller to my renderaction. I was able to submit but once I added validationmessagefor. This exception came up.

```
Here's the partial View


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Draft">
                My Drafts
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="Draft" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">

            @{
                Html.RenderAction("GetDrafts","MyPostController");
            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label>Reply To:<small>(optional)</small></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7"> 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReplyTo,null,new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReplyTo)

                </div>


            </div>
```

on top of that there's a

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {

   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="col-md-3">
    @*//side menu here*@
    @Html.Partial("_SideMenu", Model) 

</div>
```

here's the action

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get all saved drafts
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetDrafts()
    {
        var drafts = _dbrepo.GetUserDrafts();
        return PartialView("_DraftView", drafts);
    }

here is the _draftview
@model IEnumerable<Models.MyModel>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

 <div class="table-responsive">
<small>

<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostSubject)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostDate)
        </th>


        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RecCreateUser)

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostSubject)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostDate)
        </td>


        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RecCreateUser)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewDraft", new { id = item.ID}, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" }) 
        </td>


    </tr>
}

</table>
</small>
</div>
```

I tried this [Html.RenderAction Failed when Validation Failed](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/19/html.renderaction-failed-when-validation-failed.aspx)
but its throwing me an "ambiguous between the following action methods" error

So as I have mentioned. I was able to post data if modelstate isvalid. but once it is invalid. that exception comes up.
I tried commenting the renderaction for testing. and I was able to throw the validationmessage.

Comment: Check inner exception details (since `ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper` problem is very broad with tons of SO posts explained that), and which part of your code throws it.

Comment: Its the renderaction part.

Comment: Did you not understand the solution your linked to? You need 2 methods - `[HttpGet]public ActionResult GetDrafts()` and `[HttpPost]public ActionResult GetDrafts(object dummy)`, with the code in the POST method being identical to the GET method (not that the POST method signature has a 'dummy' parameter (which is not used) to avoid the error your getting

Comment: well i forgot to mention that I added this [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")] and still throws me an error. I fixed it anyway it was the multiAttribute for handling different buttons in same beginform that's causing it.